# Trying to create a column in a dataframe based on slicing another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, select

In my toy example,  I have an original dataframe `df1`.  I want to create a column in a new dataframe `df2` based on values from `df1`

If I were doing this in SQL,  it would be something like,

```
Update df2.value = (
   select df1.value where df1.settlement_date = df2.index 
        AND 
   df1.contract_date = df2.contract date
)
```

I tried to do this via slicing,  but it throws `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`

What's the clean, pythonic/panda-ic way to do procedures like this?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'2016-01-01','2016-06-01'], 
                    [2,'2016-01-01','2016-07-01'],
                    [2,'2016-01-01','2016-08-01'],
                    [2,'2016-01-02','2016-06-01'],
                    [2,'2016-01-02','2016-07-01'],
                    [2,'2016-01-02','2016-08-01'],
                    [2,'2016-01-03','2016-06-01'],
                    [2,'2016-01-03','2016-07-01'],
                    [2,'2016-01-03','2016-08-01'],
                    [2,'2016-01-04','2016-06-01'],
                    [3,'2016-01-04','2016-07-01'],
                    [4,'2016-01-04','2016-08-01']],
                   columns=['value', 'settlement_date', 'contract_date'])

df1['settlement_date'] = df1['settlement_date'].astype('datetime64')
df1['contract_date'] = df1['contract_date'].astype('datetime64')

df2 =pd.DataFrame([['2016-01-01','2016-06-01'], 
                   ['2016-01-02','2016-06-01'],
                   ['2016-01-03','2016-06-01'],
                   ['2016-01-04','2016-06-01']],
                   columns=['settlement_date', 'contract_date'])
df2['settlement_date'] = df2['settlement_date'].astype('datetime64')
df2['contract_date'] = df2['contract_date'].astype('datetime64')
df2.set_index('settlement_date', inplace=True)


df2['value']= df1[(df1['settlement_date']==df2.index) & (df1['contract_date']==df2['contract_date'])]['value']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do a `join` or a `merge` like this:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1,how="left",on=["settlement_date","contract_date"])
```

In the case above, don't use `set_index` or if you want to use index, you can use `join` instead.

Comment: Simple and straight forward